# Search Widget Pop UP

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have integrated the search widget into my action bar, when I submit the search a screen opens up (attached) which I don't want as I am calling my own customised search.  When I hit the back button, this screen is removed and my search results are displayed.

Here is the code I'm using

```
public class Main_Activity extends ActionBarActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

protected void onCreate......{

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    setupSearchView(searchItem);

    return true;
}


private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchManager != null) {
        List<SearchableInfo> searchables = searchManager.getSearchablesInGlobalSearch();

        SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        for (SearchableInfo inf : searchables) {
            if (inf.getSuggestAuthority() != null
                    && inf.getSuggestAuthority().startsWith("applications")) {
                info = inf;
            }
        }
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(info);
    }

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}


@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        handleTextSearchClickEvent(query);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  >
    <!-- Location Found -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_plus"
        android:title="@string/action_location_add"

        app:showAsAction="always"
       />

<!--divider-->
    <item android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:icon="@drawable/divider"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <!-- Search Item -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"

        app:showAsAction = "always"
        app:actionViewClass = "android.widget.SearchView"
      />
</menu>
```

Please before people give out about the code not being compilable I know that, I'm just showing the necessities...

I would just like to know, if anyone does know how to prevent this screen from displaying?!

It would be greatly appreciated

[screen shot of pop up screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dusG6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...amazing...after a long time working on it myself and breaking my own heart and no joy to a short time googling!

I had my method

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        handleTextSearchClickEvent(query);

        return false;
    }
```

return false which according to this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html

Returns
true if the query has been handled by the listener, false to let the SearchView perform the default action.

Magic!!